# how to bind the @html.dropdownlist name with id in mvc using JavaScript formate

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to bind the @html.dropdownlist in mvc using JavaScript format with name and id . I try  but not bind in the JavaScript side its not pass the value in client side. My list value format image is given below. How to pass the value with name and id not serial no .

Comment: how does the received json looks like?

Comment: then how i implement this?

Comment: can you show how does the `User` class looks like

Comment: public class User : Entity
    {

Comment: please edit the original question and add the model class there not in the comments

Comment: waht `GetAllStudents` method is returning you a List ? what type ?

Answer (score 1):

change the type to GET in your ajax request like

```
 $.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 ...
```

and try

```
$.each(data, function (index, val) {
    $('<option/>',{value:val.Id,text:val.Text}).appendTo("#MyDdl");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a SelectList to the client. This class implements `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and SelectListItem has 2 properties: `Value` and `Text` which you should bind your drop down to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: { id : id },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#MyDdl').empty();
        $.each(data, function () {
            $('#MyDdl').append(
                $('<option/>', {
                    value: this.Value,
                    html: this.Text
                })
            );
        });
    }
});
```

In your example you were using `val.Id` but there's no such property.

But as a matter of fact you don't need any SelectList. Just return the students collection:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Some(string id) 
{
    var students = service.GetAllStudents().ToList();
    students.Insert(0, new StudentModel{ Id = 0, Name = "Select student" });
    return Json(students);
}
```

and now you can bind your dropdown to the `Id` and `Name` properties of this collection:

```
$.each(data, function () {
    $('#MyDdl').append(
        $('<option/>', {
            value: this.Id,
            html: this.Name
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: hai darin , i expecting u. My problem is my json not rerun to the client side. Its not trigger in my client side

Comment: You mean the `success` callback is not trigerred? Is your controller action called? Are there some errors in your javascript console? Can you see the AJAX request sent in FireBug? Where are you calling this `$.ajax` method? Is it in a click or submit handler? If so, did you cancel the default action by returning false from this handler to prevent the browser from redirecting away? Is the `StudentModel` entity JSON serializable (i.e. it does not contain any circular references in its object graph)? Many questions that will help you find the problem.